# Replace Content for PHP Variable (HTML tags Stored)

Tags: php, html, dom

I want to replace `<a>` tag contents from PHP Variable (**`$html_content`**)...

The Variable `$html_content` Value looks like below:

```
$html_content= "<table>
<thead>
<tr><th>Customer</th><th>Age</th><th>A</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>Test 1</td><td>25</td><td><a href='www.google.com'>Link</a></td></tr>
<tr><td>Test 2</td><td>30</td><td><a href='www.yahoo.com'>Link</a></td></tr>
<tr><td>Test 3</td><td>31</td><td><a href='www.rediff.com'>Link</a></td></tr>
...
...
...
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want to replace content in string every last `<td>` content of every `<tr>` which contains `<a>` tag.

The sample rows result:

```
<tr><td>Test 1</td><td>25</td><td>Action will be taken soon.</td></tr>
<tr><td>Test 2</td><td>30</td><td>Action taken yesterday</td></tr>
...
...
```

I need result to replace every row with different content values. The content is taken from table. The particular customer action only i want to replace.

```
CUSTOMER TABLE:
------------------------------------------------------
id    customer    age    action 
------------------------------------------------------
1     Test 1      25     Action will be taken soon
2     Test 2      30     Action taken yesterday
3     Test 3      31     Action will take tomw
4     Kumar       28     Suspended
...
...
...

------------------------------------------------------
```

using this table i have shown filtered result in one page without action description instead of `<a>` tag. (This result is part of that page named `reports.php`).
I want to export these records only with `action` field description to PDF(I'm using HTML to PDF class).
In that page i had sent to these HTML values to that page and storing in PHP Variable(`$html_content`) in `export_pdf.php` page...

The **table records** is **not fixed size**... It's based on generating result from sorting.

Please anyone help me...
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following codes:

```
$html_content= preg_replace("/<a[^>]+\>(.*?)<\/a>/i", "Action will be taken soon.", $html_content);
```

With `foreach` in `query`

```
foreach($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $html_content = preg_replace("/<a[^>]+\>(\w+)<\/a>/i", $row['action'], $html_content); 
}
```

#### Output

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr><th>Customer</th><th>Age</th><th>A</th></tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr><td>Test 1</td><td>25</td><td>Action will be taken soon.</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Test 2</td><td>30</td><td>Action will be taken soon.</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Test 3</td><td>31</td><td>Action will be taken soon.</td></tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Bora your Response... But I need result to replace every row with different content values.  The content is taken from table. The particular customer action only i want to replace.

Comment: Could you give me an example or paste to question? I'll update

Comment: Bora :I edited the question... Plz see that... could u understand?

Comment: Ok, your replace texts `will be`, `yesterday` etc. Texts changes according to what? And where do you store these texts? In array? I have to know.

Comment: @Vasu Updated with `foreach`. You can replace while getting result from query with `foreach`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via regex:

```
$rgReplace = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
$i         = 0;
$html_content=preg_replace_callback('/\<td[^\<\>]*\>\<a[^\<\>]*\>[^\<\>]*\<\/a\>\<\/td\>/', 
function($rgMatches) use ($rgReplace, &$i)
{
   return $rgReplace[$i++];
}, $html_content);
```

(your `$rgReplace` is an array with desired replaces).

or, alternatively, via [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) API.

Comment: Thanks Alma Do Mundo your response.  But I need result to replace every row with different content values. The content is taken from table. The particular customer action only i want to replace. I edited the question... plz see that...