# Inserting a PHP variable into a HTML tag

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make a button go to a page like so: *http://localhost/ck/jobs/jview.php?id=8* How can I make a href within an echo to visit the page.

`Example: <a href='jobs/jview.php?id=$id'>`

```
$sql = "SELECT id, name, address, telephone_number, email, model, serial_no, status, date_booked FROM jobs";
$result = $dbconfig->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "
                        <tr>
                            <td>"; echo $row["id"]."</td>
                            <td>"; echo  $row["name"]. "</td>
                            <td>"; echo  $row["address"]. "</td>
                            <td>"; echo  $row["telephone_number"]. "</td>
                            <td>"; echo  $row["email"]. "</td>
                            <td>"; echo  $row["model"]. "</td>
                            <td>"; echo  $row["serial_no"]. "</td>
                            <td>"; echo  $row["status"]. "</td>
                            <td>"; echo  $row["date_booked"]. "</td>
                            <td><button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-circle'><i class='fa fa-file-text'></i></a></td>
                        </tr>
                    ";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$dbconfig->close();
?>
```

Comment: echo '<tr><td>'.$row[id].'</td></tr>'; echo only once, after joining every resulting string.

Comment: Does this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504629/replace-content-for-php-variable-html-tags-stored) help you?

Comment: Do this, `<td><a href="jobs/jview.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-default btn-circle"><i class="fa fa-file-text">View</i></a></td>`

Answer (score 1):

Using variables in HTML can be done in several ways.

```
echo 'some text' . $variable . ' more text';
```

or

```
echo "some text $variable more text";
```

the double quotes make the difference.

Comment: I am trying to do this `<td><?php echo .$msn.; ?></td> ` but it's not helping me out

Comment: The dots are to concatenate text, you don't need them here. Also make sure your code is in a .php file otherwise the server doesn't process it as php.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `"<td><a href='jobs/jview.php?id=$id'>jobs page</a></td>";` inside your `<tr>` element.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT id, name, address, telephone_number, email, model, serial_no, status, date_booked FROM jobs";
$result = $dbconfig->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>
                <td>".$row["id"]."</td>
                <td>".$row["name"]. "</td>
                            <td>".$row["address"]. "</td>
                            <td>".$row["telephone_number"]. "</td>
                            <td>".$row["email"]. "</td>
                            <td>".$row["model"]. "</td>
                            <td>".$row["serial_no"]. "</td>
                            <td>".$row["status"]. "</td>
                            <td>".$row["date_booked"]. "</td>
                            <td><button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-circle'><i class='fa fa-file-text'></i></a></td>
                        </tr>
                    ";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$dbconfig->close();
```

just edited your code, to the right syntax.